# LLVM API to assemble and link IR to executable

Tags: c++, linker, clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I am building a toy language in C++ using LLVM 15.0.7, following the quintessential [kaleidoscope guide](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/index.html). However, my language does not use a JIT, and is instead compiled. What I want is to be able to turn my `LLVM Module` into an executable file (i.e. an `a.out`), ideally with control over what files it links with.

My current "solution" is extremely hacky, and involves the following:

```cpp
llvm::InitializeAllTargetInfos();
llvm::InitializeAllTargets();
llvm::InitializeAllTargetMCs();
llvm::InitializeAllAsmParsers();
llvm::InitializeAllAsmPrinters();

auto TargetTriple = llvm::sys::getDefaultTargetTriple();
myLlvmModule->setTargetTriple(TargetTriple);

std::string Error;
auto Target = llvm::TargetRegistry::lookupTarget(TargetTriple, Error);
if (!Target)
    return 1;

auto CPU = "generic";
auto Features = "";

llvm::TargetOptions opt;
auto RM = llvm::Optional<llvm::Reloc::Model>();
auto TheTargetMachine =
    Target->createTargetMachine(TargetTriple, CPU, Features, opt, RM, llvm::None, llvm::CodeGenOpt::Aggressive);

myLlvmModule->setDataLayout(TheTargetMachine->createDataLayout());

auto Filename = "out.o";
std::error_code EC;
llvm::raw_fd_ostream dest(Filename, EC, llvm::sys::fs::OF_None);

if (EC)
    return 1;

llvm::legacy::PassManager pass;
auto FileType = llvm::CGFT_ObjectFile;

if (TheTargetMachine->addPassesToEmitFile(pass, dest, nullptr, FileType))
    return 1;

pass.run(*myLlvmModule);
dest.flush();

system("cc out.o");
remove("out.o");
```

Basically, I'm assembling the IR into an object file, and then passing it to Clang or GCC with `system()` where it handles the linking and emitting to an executable.

Obviously, this is not a good solution, since I have no control over what version of Clang/GCC a user has, and calling to another process like this makes my compiler no longer "self contained". Most importantly, it defeats the purpose of learning to do the steps by hand.

I *really* don't want to call `system` in my project. There has to be a better way, right? Surely other LLVM-based compilers don't do this! Surely LLVM has an API tool that takes the in-memory IR representation and outputs an executable, or alternatively a tool that links object files... right?

I tried looking into the [Object sub-directory](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/llvm/include/llvm/Object) in the LLVM source to see if maybe there's some tool that lets me manually do what that `system` call is doing, but I'm just not experienced enough with LLVM to know what to look for. I've also tried looking at other compilers for inspiration on how this is approached, but again, it's hard for me as someone new to LLVM to parse through these massive projects. There's a real lack of quality guides out there on this stuff.

Any help or guidance here would be greatly appreciated.